# Firestore -- Get only the changed documents in a large synced collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read all of the questions below, and cannot find anything in the docs to describe how to sync a collection and receive *only* changed documents from a collection. I've got over 500 documents in my synced collection (using [redux-saga-firebase syncCollection](https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/guides/syncing-data)) but usually only about 100 of them ever change. At any given time, even fewer will change, but I'm currently getting *all 500+* documents back when even one changes, which results in 500+ reads. Not ideal, and will cost me at scale.

Here is my code using redux-saga-firebase, but a vanilla firebase code answer would also suffice. How can get a synchronized response that sends *only* the changed documents in the collection?

```
export function* getPlayersFromDb() {
  yield fork(
    rsf.firestore.syncCollection,
    'players',
    { successActionCreator: response => ({
            type: t.GET_PLAYERS_FROM_DB_SUCCESS,
            payload: [...response],
        }),
        failureActionCreator: () => ({
            type: t.GET_PLAYERS_FROM_DB_FAILURE,
            payload: [],
        }),
        transform: response => messageTransformer(response),
    }
);
```

}

[Does Firestore sync only diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089835/does-firestore-sync-only-diff)

[Realm syncing with large collection on Firestore - architectural questions / issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096606/realm-syncing-with-large-collection-on-firestore-architectural-questions-iss)

[How to avoid unnecessary Firestore reads with Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700648/how-to-avoid-unnecessary-firestore-reads-with-cache)

[What exactly does Firestore synchronization do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682203/what-exactly-does-firestore-synchronization-do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firestore queries don't have a notion of querying "only things that have changed".  You will need to create that notion on your own.

Firestore doesn't make any internal record about whether or not a document has been changed. And it certainly doesn't know anything about the last time some bit of code queried a collection.

If you want to know the documents that have changed since a prior query, you will need to do two things:

1. Record in a field in each document the last time it was updated, typically with a server timestamp. Every update to a document should change this timestamp.
2. Remember in your application the last time the collection was queried, and use that time to filter the query for only the documents that were updated since that time.

Comment: Thank you for all your help as always, Doug. Does your suggestion work with synced data or would it only work in a get-where query? I'd like to not have the user  need to initiate a request.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  It doesn't matter where the query comes from.  It just needs to have the correct filter asking for documents whose updated date is greater than the last seen date.

Comment: My current implementation doesn't require sending anything (like a timestamp) from the client. When the db data changes, it just pushes the collection. Are you suggesting I add a range filter to my syncCollection query? Or that this approach won't work and I basically need to set up polling on the client?

Comment: Yes, add a filter to the query.  You can still listen to results in real time.

Comment: Wouldn't the query need to change frequently to reflect the most recent update value? Is there a way to have the query parameters change, or do you need to re-subscribe?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great article explaining some tips.

A strategy here is to add a property on each document such as `lastModified` and `.get()` from the Firebase client cache and only query the server to get documents with a `lastModified` greater than the client cache document fetch timestamp.

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e