# Get collection reference in redux-saga-firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga-firebase

I'm unable to define a collection reference using [redux-saga-firebase](https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/). I'm trying to define it like this:

```
const query = rsf.firestore.collection('players').where('up', '>', lastUpdated);
```

but I am getting

> TypeError: _firebase_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.rsf.firestore.collection is not a function

I have tried also tried using `.reference()` as described [here](https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/guides/sorting-filtering) to no avail. I'm attempting to limit the number of documents synced from a collection per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314708/firestore-get-only-the-changed-documents-in-a-large-synced-collection/62314734). How can I get a collection reference for use in this function?

```
import { rsf } from '../../firebase/firebase';

export function* getPlayersFromDb() {
  const players = yield select(getPlayers);
  const lastUpdated = Math.max(...players.map(x => x.up));
  const query = rsf.firestore.collection('players').where('up', '>', lastUpdated);

yield fork(
  rsf.firestore.syncCollection,
  query,
  { successActionCreator: response => ({
            type: t.GET_PLAYERS_FROM_DB_SUCCESS,
            payload: [...response],
        }),
        failureActionCreator: () => ({
            type: t.GET_PLAYERS_FROM_DB_FAILURE,
            payload: [],
        }),
        transform: response => messageTransformer(response),
    }
);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are mixing the official firestore SDK libraries with the redux-saga-firestore ones. If you want to get a `collectionReference` you have to do it using the official SDK, since the redux-saga-firestore libraries do not offer a method that returns that output.

So, in order to get the `collectionReference` you would need to import the Firestore SDK and use almost the same code you already have on the `getPlayersFromDb` function, and it would look like this:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
var db = firebase.firestore();

...

export function* getPlayersFromDb() {
   ...
   const query = db.collection('players').where('up', '>', lastUpdated);
   ...
}
```

**NOTE**: As you can see on this [redux-saga-firestore documentation](https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/reference/dev/firestore#getCollection), you could be using the `getCollection` method for that, but since you have a `where` clause, you would need to use a `collectionReference` to filter it anyway, so I am afraid there is no real solution for this with redux-saga-firestore.

Hope this helps